# Deltalake - Different behaviour on PySpark and Python3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have launched GCP dataproc cluster and running commands from associated Jupyter notebook and later on master node shell by ssh. However when I run the code in Python3 notebook, I'm able to read and write to/from delta table. But when I try the exact same code on PySpark notebook running into error. Also tried on shell by ssh to master node. Noticed similar behaviour, works in Python shell, but not in PySpark shell.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# spark.stop

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('test_session_3') \ # changed the session when running across notebook,shell
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-storage:2.3.0") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data = [(1,"James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    (2,"Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("emp_id",IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df_employees = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df_employees.printSchema()
df_employees.show()

# write to Delta table # Errors out here in PySpark

df_employees.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("employee_data_3") 

# read from Delta table

table_path = '/user/hive/warehouse/employee_data_3'
delta_data_read = spark.read.format("delta").load(table_path)
delta_data_read.count()
```

**Error in PySpark:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF
```

Comment: Is the Python, Spark and Java Version are the same in your both environment?

Comment: yes same. for ex: running in Jypyter - both on Python and jupyter notebook. Config on both : Kernel: /opt/conda/miniconda3/bin/python
Python version: 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:23:14) [GCC 10.4.0]
PySpark version: 3.3.0
spark version: 3.3.0